# Using post method in PHP to save data to database

Tags: php

I'm checking whether or not a text box has value or not before saving it into my database. I'm creating a movie website, so the validation is working fine.

The problem is with the saving, I'm uploading a picture with the movie. The picture is being upload to a folder into my web site application into my directory, the only problem here is that I'm always having this error code while clicking on save

> Notice: Undefined index: photoimg in C:\xampp\htdocs\star_crud\Home.php on line 233
>
> Notice: Undefined index: photoimg in C:\xampp\htdocs\star_crud\Home.php on line 234

My code is below :

```
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
   
    // keep track post values
    $cast = $_POST['cast'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $comment =$_POST['comment'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $tag = $_POST['tags'];
    $IDBM = $_POST['idbm'];
    $cast = htmlspecialchars($cast);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);
    
    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($cast)) {
        $castError = 'Please enter Cast';
        $valid = false;
    }
     
    if (empty($title)) {
        $titleError = 'Please enter Title';
        $valid = false;
    }
      if (empty($comment)) {
        $commentError = 'Please enter Comment';
        $valid = false;
    }


  if ($valid) {
    
   
        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
 
    
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
        
        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                            
                            echo "hi";
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }
            
        else
            echo "Please select image..!";
            
        exit;
    
    
    
    }
    }
    else echo "error";
```

I have done a check removing all the statement in `if(valid)` statement, and print an string, it work, I think the problem come with the statement.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" action="Home.php" method="post">



                  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($titleError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="title" type="text"  placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo !empty($title)?$title:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($titleError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $titleError;?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Year</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                       <?php 
                        $years = range (2011, 2021);
                        echo '<select name="year">';
                            foreach ($years as $value) {
                            echo "<option value=\"$value\"> $value</option>\n";
                                }
                                echo '</select>';
                       
                       ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                       <?php 
                         require 'db2.php';
                         $q1 = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT Name FROM Category ");
                        

                         echo "<select name='Category'>";
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)) {
                         echo "<option value='" . $row['Name'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                           echo "</select>";
                       ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($castError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Cast</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="cast" type="text"  placeholder="Cast" value="<?php echo !empty($cast)?$cast:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($castError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $castError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ajaxform">
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($imageError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Image Upload</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      
            


                  <input type="file" name="photoimg"  onchange="readURL(this);" id="photoimg" /><br/>
                          <img id="blah"  src="#"  height="150" width="150"  alt="your image" />
                   


                    </div>
                </div>
                    
                  </div>
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($TagsError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Tags</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="tags" id="mySingleField" type="hidden"  > <!-- only disabled for demonstration purposes -->
                         <ul id="singleFieldTags"></ul><?php if (!empty($TagsError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $TagsError;?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($IDMBError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">IDBM</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                     
                        <input name="idbm"  type="textarea"><?php if (!empty($IDMBError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $IDMBError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($CommentError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label class="control-label">Comment</label>
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="4" style="width:780px" cols="50">
                    </textarea>
                    <?php if (!empty($commentError)): ?>
                            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $commentError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <div class="controls">
                     
                        
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-actions">
                      <button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                      <a class="btn" href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please show your form. Does it use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? This is required for file uploading.

Comment: @Barmar i edit the question and put the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

photoimg should be the name of your input field:

```
<input type='file' name='photoimg' />
```

Since it probably isn't, the offset of the $_FILES array doesn't work, and PHP can't access any of the sub-keys (tmp_name, etc).

Comment: it is the same   <input type="file" name="photoimg"  onchange="readURL(this);" id="photoimg" /><br/> look

Answer (score 1):

Change the form to:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" action="Home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to enable file uploads.